# Uninstall GhostScript installed from source on CentOS server

Tags: centos, ghostscript

I have installed GhostScript 9.21 from source into /usr/local and want to remove it and use the OS-default version instead. The GS Makefile has no "uninstall" option and I cannot find any articles that specifically target the version installed from source.

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP and GhostScript 9.21, I have generated the following file list which does the trick:

```
rm -rf /usr/local/bin/dvipdf
rm -rf /usr/local/bin/eps2eps
rm -rf /usr/local/bin/font2c
rm -rf /usr/local/bin/gs
rm -rf /usr/local/bin/gsbj
rm -rf /usr/local/bin/gsdj
rm -rf /usr/local/bin/gsdj500
rm -rf /usr/local/bin/gslj
rm -rf /usr/local/bin/gslp
rm -rf /usr/local/bin/gsnd
rm -rf /usr/local/bin/lprsetup.sh
rm -rf /usr/local/bin/pdf2dsc
rm -rf /usr/local/bin/pdf2ps
rm -rf /usr/local/bin/pf2afm
rm -rf /usr/local/bin/pfbtopfa
rm -rf /usr/local/bin/pphs
rm -rf /usr/local/bin/printafm
rm -rf /usr/local/bin/ps2ascii
rm -rf /usr/local/bin/ps2epsi
rm -rf /usr/local/bin/ps2pdf
rm -rf /usr/local/bin/ps2pdf12
rm -rf /usr/local/bin/ps2pdf13
rm -rf /usr/local/bin/ps2pdf14
rm -rf /usr/local/bin/ps2pdfwr
rm -rf /usr/local/bin/ps2ps
rm -rf /usr/local/bin/ps2ps2
rm -rf /usr/local/bin/unix-lpr.sh
rm -rf /usr/local/bin/wftopfa
rm -rf /usr/local/share/ghostscript
rm -rf /usr/local/share/man/de/man1/dvipdf.1
rm -rf /usr/local/share/man/de/man1/eps2eps.1
rm -rf /usr/local/share/man/de/man1/font2c.1
rm -rf /usr/local/share/man/de/man1/gsnd.1
rm -rf /usr/local/share/man/de/man1/pdf2dsc.1
rm -rf /usr/local/share/man/de/man1/pdf2ps.1
rm -rf /usr/local/share/man/de/man1/printafm.1
rm -rf /usr/local/share/man/de/man1/ps2ascii.1
rm -rf /usr/local/share/man/de/man1/ps2pdf.1
rm -rf /usr/local/share/man/de/man1/ps2pdf12.1
rm -rf /usr/local/share/man/de/man1/ps2pdf13.1
rm -rf /usr/local/share/man/de/man1/ps2pdf14.1
rm -rf /usr/local/share/man/de/man1/ps2ps.1
rm -rf /usr/local/share/man/de/man1/wftopfa.1
rm -rf /usr/local/share/man/man1/dvipdf.1
rm -rf /usr/local/share/man/man1/eps2eps.1
rm -rf /usr/local/share/man/man1/font2c.1
rm -rf /usr/local/share/man/man1/gs.1
rm -rf /usr/local/share/man/man1/gsbj.1
rm -rf /usr/local/share/man/man1/gsdj.1
rm -rf /usr/local/share/man/man1/gsdj500.1
rm -rf /usr/local/share/man/man1/gslj.1
rm -rf /usr/local/share/man/man1/gslp.1
rm -rf /usr/local/share/man/man1/gsnd.1
rm -rf /usr/local/share/man/man1/pdf2dsc.1
rm -rf /usr/local/share/man/man1/pdf2ps.1
rm -rf /usr/local/share/man/man1/pf2afm.1
rm -rf /usr/local/share/man/man1/pfbtopfa.1
rm -rf /usr/local/share/man/man1/printafm.1
rm -rf /usr/local/share/man/man1/ps2ascii.1
rm -rf /usr/local/share/man/man1/ps2epsi.1
rm -rf /usr/local/share/man/man1/ps2pdf.1
rm -rf /usr/local/share/man/man1/ps2pdf12.1
rm -rf /usr/local/share/man/man1/ps2pdf13.1
rm -rf /usr/local/share/man/man1/ps2pdf14.1
rm -rf /usr/local/share/man/man1/ps2pdfwr.1
rm -rf /usr/local/share/man/man1/ps2ps.1
rm -rf /usr/local/share/man/man1/wftopfa.1
```